# How to use replace &amp; with & in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Problem:** I am having a hard time to replace"&amp ;" to &. Is their a way to use javascript to replace the ampersand to &.

```
<div class="col-md-4 no-margin padding" id="change">
 <strong>Specialty: </strong>{{e.Specialty}}
</div>
```

I would like to replace the "&amp ;" when it grabs the data from the database to "&".

So currently, it will display "Nursing &amp ; Doctor" rather then "Nursing & Doctor"

How can I achieve this using replace. I have tried ng-show, Santize, and ng-bind-html but have not worked out for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is not necessarily the best way but for those of you that need to do this you can use this:

```js
var parser = new DOMParser;
var dom = parser.parseFromString(YOURSTRING,'text/html');
var decodedString = dom.body.textContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use $sce service and trustAsHtml so that Angular will not do the encoding and display the output without output encoding. Details are here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Steps are below-

1. Include ngSanitize module - angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
2. Inject $sce service in your controller
3. Truest output using - vm.Specialty= $sce.trustAsHtml(Specialty);
4. Display to the user without output encoding -  **Specialty:** bind-html-compile=e.Specialty

Comment: @ ManishSingh: not sure how to do step 3. where would that go?

Comment: It should be implemented in controller

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using

```
<span ng-bind-html="e.Specialty"></span>
```

and include `['ngSanitize']` in your module

plunkr example:  https://plnkr.co/edit/d6Anjr7vL6un9d0yL5ZW?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I would use a filter...

JavaScript:

```
myApp.filter('andFilter', function() {
  return function(item) {
    return item.replace(/&amp ;/g, '&');
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 no-margin padding" id="change">
 <strong>Specialty: </strong>{{e.Specialty | andFilter}}
</div>
```

Comment: The space between the &amp and semicolon should be removed to replace &amp;